# Why is NSExpression incorrectly evaluating this math expression?

Tags: objective-c, nsexpression

I have the following code:

```
NSExpression *expression;

@try {
    expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"20/100*200"];

    NSNumber *result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
}
@catch(NSException *exception){}
```

Somehow, the result I'm getting back is an `NSNumber` of `0`, instead of `40`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing an integer division instead of a floating point one. Try this:

```
expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"20.0/100*200"];
```